# How can I correctly read in multiple files inside a Gulp task?

Tags: javascript, gulp, build-system

I have a Gulp task that renders a file containing a Lodash template and puts it in my build directory. I use [gulp-template](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-template) to do the rendering.

To render correctly, my template needs to be passed a list of files from my build directory. I get this list using [glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob). Since the glob API is asynchronous, I'm forced to write my task like this:

```
gulp.task('render', function() {
    glob('src/**/*.js', function (err, appJsFiles) {

        // Get rid of the first path component.
        appJsFiles = _.map(appJsFiles, function(f) {
            return f.slice(6);
        });

        // Render the file.
        gulp.src('src/template.html')
            .pipe(template({
                scripts: appJsFiles,
                styles: ['style1.css', 'style2.css', 'style3.css']
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(config.build_dir));
    });
});
```

This seems inelegant to me. Is there a better way to write this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to fix your specific problem is to use the [synchronous mode for glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#globsyncpattern-options), which is in the docs you linked to.  Then return the result of `gulp.src`.

```
gulp.task('render', function() {
    var appJsFiles = _.map(glob.sync('src/**/*.js'), function(f) {
        return f.slice(6);
    });
    // Render the file.
    return gulp.src('src/template.html')
        .pipe(template({
            scripts: appJsFiles,
            styles: ['style1.css', 'style2.css', 'style3.css']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.build_dir));
});
```

Comment: I had no idea glob had a synchronous mode. This should teach me to RTFM :/

Answer (score 0):

If you want a task to run asynchronously, take in a callback.

```
gulp.task('render', function(cb) {
    glob('src/**/*.js', function (err, appJsFiles) {
        if (err) {
            return cb(err);
        }

        // Get rid of the first path component.
        appJsFiles = _.map(appJsFiles, function(f) {
            return f.slice(6);
        });

        // Render the file.
        gulp.src('src/template.html')
            .pipe(template({
                scripts: appJsFiles,
                styles: ['style1.css', 'style2.css', 'style3.css']
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(config.build_dir))
            .on('end', cb);
   });
});
```

Comment: this `cb()` doesn't ever exit gulp

Comment: Try it now, missed the gulp.src stream.

Comment: I don't want to do `gulp.src`. I need my own list of file objects w/ meta data. Is it not possible?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: For some reason. Certain gulp tasks don't exit. They just hang when finished.

Comment: @chovy: The asychronous gulp task is not exiting in my case as well. I am using callback for exiting. Did you find any workaround to overcome this issue?

Comment: Nope.  Not yet  Still hangs for me.